# Best performance in reading million records of data

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

I have a database with a large number of data (millions of rows), and also is updating during the day with large number of data, I have a back up of this database for reporting, so getting report of data does not affect on the performance of main database.

For syncing back up database with main database, I wrote a windows service which queries the main database and inserts new data into backup database... every time the query gets 5000 rows from the main database...

### EDIT:

the query is like below:

```
const string cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM [RLCConvertor].[dbo].[RLCDiffHeader] WHERE ID >= @Start and ID <= @End";
```

Here is the code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);               
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", start);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", end);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var rldDiffId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString());
                var rlcDifHeader = new RLCDiffHeader
                {
                    Tech_head_Type = long.Parse(reader["Tech_head_Type"].ToString()),
                    ItemCode = long.Parse(reader["ItemCode"].ToString()),
                    SessionNumber = long.Parse(reader["SessionNumber"].ToString()),                        
                    MarketFeedCode = reader["MarketFeedCode"].ToString(),
                    MarketPlaceCode = reader["MarketPlaceCode"].ToString(),
                    FinancialMarketCode = reader["FinancialMarketCode"].ToString(),
                    CIDGrc = reader["CIDGrc"].ToString(),
                    InstrumentID = reader["InstrumentID"].ToString(),
                    CValMNE = reader["CValMNE"].ToString(),
                    DEven = reader["DEven"].ToString(),
                    HEven = reader["HEven"].ToString(),
                    MessageCodeType = reader["MessageCodeType"].ToString(),
                    SEQbyINSTandType = reader["SEQbyINSTandType"].ToString()                                            
                };
                newRLCDiffHeaders.Add(rldDiffId, rlcDifHeader);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

but when I started the service... the performance of main database got worse... is the code not efficient? Is there any better way? Because I searched and found that `dataReader` is the best for this case... or should I use `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: No, using `SqlDataAdapter` is definitely not a more efficient way to do things. The one thing I'd recommend - try a smaller size... 5000 rows *could* lead SQL Server to do **lock escalation** and lock an entire table - instead of having row-level locks. Use 2000 rows or something like that.

Comment: Also - have you looked at [SQL Server replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) which would do all of this for you - and it's right there in the product, tuned for max performance ....

Comment: For the database performance, your queries sent to db are more important than using DataTable or DataReader. You can read uncommited data with nolock keyword.

Comment: For me, the most interesting part of this question would be the contents of `cmdStr` - without that, all we have is "I have some code that reads from a data-reader" - that, *by itself* is fine and is not inefficient. But: what command are you running, and how often are you running it? My *assumption* is that any performance loss here relates to time spent **at the DB server** - but you should profile it to find out - there is nothing there that suggests a .NET performance issue

Comment: @Marc GravellYes,Yes..right,I've just edited my Question..but the query is simple..it is just a select with a where clause.

Comment: @Mecek , Could you please explain the "You can read uncommited data with nolock keyword" more?? as I said above the query is simple..just a select wiht a where cluase.

Comment: @Paridokht is there a clustered index on `ID` ? Re the `nolock` - that would be: `SELECT * FROM [RLCConvertor].[dbo].[RLCDiffHeader] with (nolock) WHERE ID >= @Start and ID <= @End` - this will avoid issues if you are being adversely affected by blocking, but will mean you might be doing dirty reads

Comment: @MarcGravell: I've just defined a new Index on a column..I think the performance will get better..but I have to wait until tomorrow to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot treat this an a correct answer or solution for your problem.
Since the comment goes big, I am providing a solution to you.

Can you try using the concept of `Ad hoc` queries

Using this you can query another database using the following way

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Seattle1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT GroupName, Name, DepartmentID
      FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department
      ORDER BY GroupName, Name') AS a;
```

Read more 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Since you are using a service, the service account surely have access to read the main db and insert to report db. I will suggest you to have a SP in your report DB , that can access the main DB using `OpenRowSet` and insert to it.

Query will be similar like this.

```
Insert into tbl
SELECT a.*
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Seattle1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
         'SELECT GroupName, Name, DepartmentID
          FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department
          ORDER BY GroupName, Name') AS a;
```

Form the service, you need to invoke the SP.
We had a similar issue and this was done by openrowset and I don't know how much performance impact this can provide. But I suggest you to do a POC and just analyze it.
Once again please consider this as a suggestion.

Comment: but I have a specific save method which  I have to use for saving new data in to report db..I can not use `SP` to insert new data..becuase it is not support `OOP` programming, I Think.

Comment: whats is OOP programming ? You mean Object Oriented Programming ? Please show the save method. I think you are using an EF thing ?

Comment: It is really not clear to me why you are advocating `OPENROWSET` here - there seems to be no compelling argument for that here..

Comment: @VeeKayBee, I'm not using `EF`, as you can see the `SqlDataReader` and `Sqlcommand` and etc...and I think may be the save method is not important because save method has a connection to another db (report db)..the bottle neck is when I want to read from the main db.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am suggested OPENROWSET because, using the OPENROWSET we can query database (maindb) using a select query and get the records inserted to another (reportdb). Our task is to replicate the records to another db using a condition. If its possible with SQL server itself, we need a mechanism to invoke the query (win service).